# Tensorflow Lite: about input shape in tflite file

Tags: tensorflow

When I use the command below to generate tflite file:

```
  ./bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco  \
  --input_file=./model1.pb \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --output_file=./model_none.tflite --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --input_type=FLOAT --input_arrays=x \
  --output_arrays=output --input_shapes=1,none,none,1
```

error:
F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/model_cmdline_flags.cc:337] Check failed: absl::SimpleAtoi(dim_str, &size) Failed to parse input_shape: 1,none,none,1

Question:
Is none shape not supported by lite?
Why google not support none shape in lite?
Is there difficult? Or just lite is not finished?
Thanks a lot for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a specific shape at conversion time. It is possible at inference time (in the interpeter API) to resize the input and have the computation size be changed. Computations are much more efficient on fixed known sizes. That is why it is required.

Comment: @huangwenhui please remember to mark answers as accepted solution if it helped you with your question.

Comment: @aselle Say you were passing in images of varying sizes, say 192x192 down to 48x48. Surely it would be more efficient to allow dynamic sizes rather than significantly padding the smaller images?

Answer (score 0):

The input shape in my pb file is (None, None, None, 3). Now I use the command to convert to tflite file:

```
./bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco \ --input_file=/home/hwh/pnet.pb \ --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE \ --output_file=/home/hwh/pnet.tflite --inference_type=FLOAT \ --input_type=FLOAT --input_arrays=pnet/input \ --output_arrays=pnet/prob1 --input_shapes=1,299,299,3
```

The tflite file is OK. But it looks the input bitmap should only be 299*299. I expect the size of input bitmap for my model can be resized, such as can be 299*299, 150*150.... Now the input size of input bitmap if not same as the size in command of converting to tflite. the error will be as below when running on java demo:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(32697): FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraBackground
E/AndroidRuntime(32697): Process: android.example.com.tflitecamerademo, PID: 32697
E/AndroidRuntime(32697): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input error: Failed to get input dimensions. 0-th input should have 1072812 bytes, but found 270000 bytes.
E/AndroidRuntime(32697):    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.getInputDims(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32697):    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:109)
E/AndroidRuntime(32697):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:166)
E/AndroidRuntime(32697):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(32697):    at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.ImageClassifierFloatInception.runInference(ImageClassifierFloatInception.java:108)
```

Answer (score 0):

According a issue in github tensorflow page, dynamic shapes are not available in TFLite.

[You can track the issue from here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29590)